# Optimizing Java Array Copy

Tags: java, arrays

So for my research group I am attempting to convert some old C++ code to Java and am running into an issue where in the C++ code it does the following:

```
    method(array+i, other parameters)
```

Now I know that Java does not support pointer arithmetic, so I got around this by copying the subarray from array+i to the end of array into a new array, but this causes the code to run horribly slow (I.e. 100x slower than the C++ version). Is there a way to get around this? I saw someone mention a built-in method on here, but is that any faster?

Comment: Are you using `System.arraycopy()`?

Comment: No, I had just been manually copying the subarray into a new one. Is System.arraycopy() significantly fasteer?

Comment: As the answers indicate, the equivalent Java idiom is to pass the a reference to the original array along with a start index. The core JDK classes are full of examples of such usage - many methods that accept an array are overloaded to also accept an array and a start/end index to operate on a slice of the array. See for example `String(char[] value)` vs. `String(char[] value, int offset, int count)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not only does your code become slower, it also changes the semantic of what is happening: when you make a call in C++, no array copying is done, so any change the `method` may apply to the array is happening in the original, not in the throw-away copy.

To achieve the same effect in Java change the signature of your function as follows:

```
void method(array, offset, other parameters)
```

Now the caller has to pass the position in the array that the `method` should consider the "virtual zero" of the array. In other words, instead of writing something like

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != N ; i++)
    ...
```

you would have to write

```
for (int i = offset ; i != offset+N ; i++)
    ...
```

This would preserve the C++ semantic of passing an array to a member function.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ function probably relied on processing from the beginning of the `array`.  In Java it should be configured to run from an offset into the array so the array doesn't need to be copied.  Copying the array, even with `System.arraycopy`, would take a significant amount of time.

It could be defined as a Java method with something like this:

```
void method(<somearraytype> array, int offset, other parameters)
```

Then the method would start at the offset into the array, and it would be called something like this:

```
method(array, i, other parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to pass a sub-array to a method, an alternative to copying the sub-array into a new array would be to pass the entire array with an additional `offset` parameter that indicates the first relevant index of the array. This would require changes in the implementation of `method`, but if performance is an issue, that's probably the most efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to handle this is to refactor the method, to take signature

```
method(int[] array, int i, other parameters)
```

so that you pass the whole array (by reference), and then tell the method where to start its processing from. Then you don't need to do any copying.